# How to find out what is causing vibration when sending and receiving texts?

Tags: sms, 8.0-oreo, vibration, lg-v20

After updating my LG V20 phone to 8.0, everytime I get a text message my phone vibrates twice. My phone has also started vibrating when I send a text.
I am using the message app that came with the phone.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked in the settings of your messaging app that there is no vibration related setting in it? Does the vibrations occur regardless of that setting?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? My LG G5 is doing the same thing- vibrating after I send a text or after I hang up a call. It's really annoying because it seems like it's vibrating for a new notification. If I could even just change the pattern of the post-text vibration that would be better.